# Can't find image to remove

Tags: images, errors, footer

I noticed when debugging my first ever Wordpress site that I was getting an error

> Access to image at
> 'http://192.168.1.250/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/bg-10-free-img.jpg' from origin 'http://my.domain.name:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy

So this image appears to be left over from the default theme but the thing is I can't find it. I am using Elementor to edit.

Doing a search of the raw HTML I found the reference in a huge block of code which is bounded by `<style id="astra-theme-css-inline-css">`

Here is the relevant code snippet

```
.site-primary-footer-wrap{padding-top:45px;padding-bottom:45px;}.site-primary-footer-wrap[data-section="section-primary-footer-builder"]{background-image:linear-gradient(to right,#101218,#101218),url(http://192.168.1.250/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/bg-10-free-img.jpg);;background-repeat:repeat;background-position:center center;background-size:cover;background-attachment:fixed;border-style:solid;border-width:0px;border-top-width:1px;border-top-color:#e6e6e6;}
```

So I believe the image is somewhere in the footer but I can't find it to delete it. My question is how can I fix this annoying error?

Comment: astra-theme-css-inline-css seems pretty self explanatory. Have you looked in the Astra theme settings?

Comment: If you mean in CUSTOMISE>>FOOTER BUILDER I have looked at all the entries I have and changed colours looking for a hidden image but I can't see it?

Comment: Have you checked other settings? This is really a question for the theme author, as third party themes are off topic here.

Comment: OK the theme is Astra. It had a bunch of images which have all been replaced by mine but this pesky hidden one is annoying me. Even though this is a bit OT I was hoping for some generic advice about how to find an image like this

Comment: Well as I pointed out, it’s in CSS generated by Astra so it must be in the Astra settings somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately for those that might come across this in the future I am not sure if this solution will help you. As I worked out the offending image was in the footer. I ended up just clicking on various options in CUSTOMISE>>FOOTER BUILDER and then I selected the PRIMARY FOOTER and found BACKGROUND which has options of COLOR/ GRADIENT/ IMAGE and when I selected IMAGE there was a broken image link icon and the option to "Remove Image". So difficult to find but fixed now.